# equivalent of navigator.bluetooth.requestdevice() in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am converting a vanilla project into react native and got stuck in this finding equivalent of `navigator.bluetooth.requestdevice()` in react native.

I have tried packages like [https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but the problem is I have the code of that web project and finding this alternative can solve many tasks.

Comment: What does `navigator.bluetooth.requestdevice()` do? Could you maybe [edit] your question and add the code of your vanilla project and what you already accomplished with react native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyone who is trying to configure BLE in reacts native application but doesn't have a full idea about it let me give you a brief explanation as I was one of you.

There are not many packages out there with the maintained author so you have to rely on this  https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager package only or you have to get a response back from the natively build package by your self...

but not to worry because there aren't any major changes and its GitHub page is well-documented.

in my case, I was looking for a specific services id and Specific characteristic id to locate while looking for devices.. this package has serval events that can help you with it.. if you need detailed explanations please comment on this..